# Allow only one decimal point in EditText

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to add an InputFilter to my EditText which must allow only integers or decimal numbers with only one decimal point.

Accepted input must be:

```
1 - 12 - 3.33 - 4.20 etc.
```

Refused:

```
.0 - 5. - 5.5.5 - 40.21.1 etc.
```

I've created a custom InputFilter which check if the input match following RegExp `^\d+(\.\d+)?$`

But instead EditText always shows an empty string, in debug "spanned" is always empty while by default the EditText has a starting value.

Filter:

```
public class DecimalDigitsFilter implements InputFilter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, Spanned spanned, int i2, int i3) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(spanned);
        if (!matcher.matches()){
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
quantita.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsFilter()});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move mo logics in `TextChangedListener` as in `InputFilter` i wasn't able to get the whole string where to check my RegExp.

Furthermore i had even to change my RegExp a bit like this `^\d+(\.([\d+]+)?)?$` i had to set values after decimal point as optionable else the `.matches()` was going to fail every time i was writing a decimal point.

So the final code looks like this:

```
quantita.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d+(\\.([\\d+]+)?)?$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(quantita.getText().toString());
        if (!matcher.matches()){
            quantita.setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the matcher against the actual text in the `EditText`:

```java
public class DecimalDigitsFilter implements InputFilter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, Spanned spanned, int i2, int i3) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(spanned.getText());
        if (!matcher.matches()){
            return "";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: cherSequence contains only the newly added char

Comment: Try using `spanned.getText()`.  If this _also_ won't work, then the method signature doesn't have the text you need here.

Comment: It's the first time i'm  making a custom filter like this so idk how to get it, but anyway i solved the issue by setting the pattern check in `TextChangedListener > afterTextChanged` as here i can access the whole string.